# Exclude certain category from latest updates

Tags: categories, exclude

I am creating a website. There is a column for latest updates. 
This is the code that i have now. I don't really good in php coding. Would like to get guidance from someone.

```
<?php
 $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=DESC&orderby=date');
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
<span class="button">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
```

But, i would like to exclude some posts from certain categories. Is there any solution to make it happen? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the answer by Tim, one can always use a proper [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). All the build in tag and category parameters gets converted to a proper `tax_query` before being passed to the `WP_Tax_Query` class to build the `JOIN` clause for the SQL query.

I use a `tax_query` in almost all applications as it gives one a lot of flexibilty, specially when it comes to child terms, exclusions of multiple terms and even multiple taxonomies. Maybe the only downfall is that you cannot use the string syntax here as in the OP, bacause a `tax_query` is an array, one should use the array syntax for the query args

In short, to exclude categories, you can try the following

```
$args = [
    // Your other args
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy'         => 'category',
            'field'            => 'term_id',
            'terms'            => [1,2,3], // Array of term ids to exclude
            'operator'         => 'NOT IN', // Exclude
        'exclude_children' => false // Do not exclude the child terms from the terms defined to exclude
        ]
    ]
];
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Pieter, this seems like having better flexibility. Should i put this entire code in the `page` or `functions.php`?

Comment: you should use it to extend your existing code

Answer (score 4):

From a quick look at the [documentation for get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/), it doesn't look like you can exclude a post based on its category.

**EDIT:** Actually, thanks to [AntonChanning](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/5077/antonchanning), turns out you can - just add `&cat=-1` to your argument string, where 1 is the ID of the category you wish to exclude:

```
$postslist = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=DESC&orderby=date&cat=-1');
```

You can also add multiple categories to this if you need to, eg. `cat=-1,-2,-3`

---

The preferred 'Wordpress way' to do this is [using WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

If you want to do it this way, instead of your call to `get_posts()`, you'll need to create a new instance of WP_Query and pass your arguments through in an array.  From the above link under the *Category Parameters* heading:

> category__not_in (array) – use category id

That's the argument you'll want to use to exclude a category:

```
$postslist = new WP_Query(array(
  "post_type" => "post",
  "posts_per_page" => 1,
  "order" => "DESC"
  "orderby" => "date",
  "category__not_in" => 1,
));
```

You'll notice I also added the 'post' post type to mimic the behaviour you would have had with `get_posts()`, and the `posts_per_page` parameter is the way to specify the number of posts returned with WP_Query.

One other change you'll need to make if you do go down this WP_Query route is to use a `while` loop instead of the `foreach` you currently have. There's [clear usage examples](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) under the *Usage* heading in the docs so I'll avoid copying and pasting them out.

Good luck!

Comment: Any argument that is valid for `WP_Query` is valid for `get_posts`. `get_posts` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query`. All arguments (*except a couple like `numberposts` and `include` and `exclude`*) are passed unchanged/unmodified to `WP_Query` as is ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen That makes two things I learnt while responding to this! Thanks Pieter.

Comment: To exclude multiple categories, just deliminate with a comma: cat=-1,-2,-3

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this @AntonChanning. I've just added that to the post too.